# Forward fill in pandas based on the another column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe, data-manipulation

**Update:**
I have a large pandas dataframe with admitTime, dischargeTime, pat_name, pat_rec and it has around 5 million records.  I am trying to forward fill the columns dischargeTime, pat_name, based on the dischargeTime datetime value for rest of the columns and break after that.

df:

`admitTime               dischargeTime      pat_name     pat_rec

2013-12-23 20:20:30    2013-12-23 21:12:00     Alex         A4536

2013-12-23 21:00:30
2013-12-23 21:01:00
2013-12-23 21:01:30
2013-12-23 21:02:00
2013-12-23 21:02:30
2013-12-23 21:03:00
2013-12-23 21:03:30
2013-12-23 21:04:00
2013-12-23 21:04:30
2013-12-23 21:05:00
2013-12-23 21:05:30
2013-12-23 21:06:00
2013-12-23 21:06:30
2013-12-23 21:07:00
2013-12-23 21:07:30
2013-12-23 21:08:00
2013-12-23 21:08:30
2013-12-23 21:09:00
2013-12-23 21:09:30
2013-12-23 21:10:00
2013-12-23 21:10:30
2013-12-23 21:11:00
2013-12-23 21:11:30
2013-12-23 21:12:00
2013-12-23 21:12:30
2013-12-23 21:13:00
2013-12-23 21:13:30
2013-12-23 21:14:00    2013-12-21:18:00      Sam          A4523
2013-12-23 21:14:30
2013-12-23 21:15:00
2013-12-23 21:15:30
2013-12-23 21:16:00
2013-12-23 21:16:30
2013-12-23 21:17:00
2013-12-23 21:17:30
2013-12-23 21:18:00
2013-12-23 21:18:30
2013-12-23 21:19:00
2013-12-23 21:19:30
2013-12-23 21:20:00`

Ideally I'd like my df to look like

`datetime                discchargeTime     pat_name   pat_rec

2013-12-23 20:20:30    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536

2013-12-23 21:00:30    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:01:00    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:01:30    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:02:00    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:02:30    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:03:00    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:03:30    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:04:00    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:04:30    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:05:00    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:05:30    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:06:00    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:06:30    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:07:00    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:07:30    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:08:00    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:08:30    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:09:00    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:09:30    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:10:00    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:10:30    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:11:00    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:11:30    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:12:00    2013-12-23 21:12:00   Alex      A4536
2013-12-23 21:12:30
2013-12-23 21:13:00
2013-12-23 21:13:30
2013-12-23 21:14:00    2013-12-21:18:00      Sam       A4523
2013-12-23 21:14:30    2013-12-21:18:00      Sam       A4523
2013-12-23 21:15:00    2013-12-21:18:00      Sam       A4523
2013-12-23 21:15:30    2013-12-21:18:00      Sam       A4523
2013-12-23 21:16:00    2013-12-21:18:00      Sam       A4523
2013-12-23 21:16:30    2013-12-21:18:00      Sam       A4523
2013-12-23 21:17:00    2013-12-21:18:00      Sam       A4523
2013-12-23 21:17:30    2013-12-21:18:00      Sam       A4523
2013-12-23 21:18:00    2013-12-21:18:00      Sam       A4523
2013-12-23 21:18:30
2013-12-23 21:19:00
2013-12-23 21:19:30
2013-12-23 21:20:00`

I tried `df[column_name].ffill()` but later realized its not the right thing to do.

I would really appreciate if I can get any suggestions.

Comment: you would require to create a mask the values which you dont want to `ffill` and then perform and `ffill` on the remaining. Post this just `concat` both results. Check my answer below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below :

```
mask = df['admitTime'] > df['dischargeTime'].iloc[0] #masking where admit time is greater than discharge time
pd.concat([df[~mask].ffill(),df[mask]]) #ffill the remaining and concat with mask

    admitTime           dischargeTime      pat_name pat_rec
0   2013-12-23 20:20:30 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
1   2013-12-23 21:00:30 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
2   2013-12-23 21:01:00 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
3   2013-12-23 21:01:30 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
4   2013-12-23 21:02:00 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
5   2013-12-23 21:02:30 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
6   2013-12-23 21:03:00 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
7   2013-12-23 21:03:30 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
8   2013-12-23 21:04:00 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
9   2013-12-23 21:04:30 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
10  2013-12-23 21:05:00 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
11  2013-12-23 21:05:30 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
12  2013-12-23 21:06:00 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
13  2013-12-23 21:06:30 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
14  2013-12-23 21:07:00 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
15  2013-12-23 21:07:30 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
16  2013-12-23 21:08:00 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
17  2013-12-23 21:08:30 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
18  2013-12-23 21:09:00 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
19  2013-12-23 21:09:30 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
20  2013-12-23 21:10:00 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
21  2013-12-23 21:10:30 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
22  2013-12-23 21:11:00 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
23  2013-12-23 21:11:30 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
24  2013-12-23 21:12:00 2013-12-23 21:12:00 Alex    A4536
25  2013-12-23 21:12:30 NaT                 NaN     NaN
26  2013-12-23 21:13:00 NaT                 NaN     NaN
................
................
```

You can then replace the nan with space if you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: Pleasure :) all the best